# Liferay AuthenticationProvider token

Tags: java, ldap, liferay

I would like to know if there is any sample example of Liferay's Authentication Provider connecting to the LDAP(Active Directory).

Any help would be useful.

thanks
Lokesh

Answer (score 0):

Following links can help you in this regard:

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/LDAP+with+AD+in+Liferay+6.0.5

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/02/life-ray-ldap-integration.html

HTH.